# JTextField грузит процессор

Tags: java, swing

У меня такая проблемка возникла. Когда я нажимаю в программе на JTextField, потом нажимаю на другое какое-то окно (например диспетчер задач), потом обратно кликаю на JTextField (не обязательно тот же) и загрузка процессора на компьютере сразу взлетает с 5% до 100%. Но если нажать на любую кнопку в программе, то загрузка ЦП спадает обратно до 5%. Кто-то может объяснить в чём проблема?

Comment: Нужен код и описание, что делает приложение. чувствую JTextField здесь ни при чем...

Comment: Да в том то и дело, что кода нет. Просто добавил на форму два поля и такая же лажа

Comment: Вы на бумаге их добавили? Или же все таки IDE? Покажите что есть.